# Custom model date field did not save current time in table

Tags: model, module, date, table

I have create `an model` in magento at a `custom module` and  in that model i have `create  table` and that `table have  a date field` and i want `save my current date in that date field` but it `becomes inserted  value null at that table`

**Table Sql:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `social` (
  `social_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image` text NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caption_text` text,
  `comments` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `insert_time` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`instagram_id`),
  KEY `likes` (`likes`,`insert_time`),
  KEY `comments` (`comments`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

**Model insert  code:**

```
$data=array(
'image'=>$url,
'likes'=>$item->likes->count,
'caption_text'=>$item->caption->text,
'comments' =>$item->comments->count,
'insert_time'=>date ('Y-M-d'), 
);
$model=Mage::getModel('social/social')->addData($data);
$model->save();
```

Why in date filed **insert_time save all value as Null** instead of current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date('Y-M-d')` will produce `2015-Jan-14` and you probably want `date('Y-m-d')` which will give you `2015-01-14`